# What is the most appropriate way to promote yourself using Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

With the new jobs board and podcast discussions on employers searching over Stack Overflow for information about applicants, what is the most appropriate way to promote yourself using Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Answer questions!

Build up a reputation by providing many quality answers, and then include good information in the ad hoc section of your profile.

Comment: I upvoted you, but the answer is kind of obvious. Is that really what he meant?

Comment: Well, it is the basis of everything. Good answers and thoughtful questions and then talk about it.

Answer (score 9):

Double check spelling and grammar before posting.  A lot of employers will be turned off by minor grammatical errors.  Firefox has a built in spell checker if you need one.

You can always go back later and edit your entries for accuracy too.  Maybe have someone proof your grammar.

You might take some of your top rated answers / questions and expand them to be more complete.  Then include a reference to those answers in your resume.

Comment: Google chrome has one too (though it doesn't recognise Google)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Joel Coehoorn's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/741/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-promote-yourself-using-stack-overflow/744#744): put your [flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair) on your website or blog.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few MVP types deliberately promoting their own sites on SO and SF.  There is a fine line between this and spam but as long as the material is relevant I don't see any issue with blowing ones own trumpet.  If the postings are offensively spam-ish they will get flagged so the system has built-in checks and balances that prevent this anyway.

I don't really use SO as a promotional tool (possibly I could), although some of my longer answers are verging on white papers and might be worth rehashing as such.  I think that a personal or professional web site is probably a better front-end but you could link to particular SO answers if you have anything you are particularly proud of.  The reverse is also true.  If you have a site with significant material (even a halfway decent technical blog) you could fan out to it from SO.

Comment: agree, relevance is the #1 issue here. We have had some private email exchange with a handful of users (nobody you would know, I think) where blatant promotion has been a problem.

Comment: And if you see this, flag it, as usual.

Comment: The "MVP types" claim would surprise me (unless it is something I've done?). Would you care to expand on that (I am genuinely interested). We do see company-based advertising, but we "deal" with that...

Comment: I won't name names as the particular examples haven't done anything grossly inappropriate.  Loosely, I'm defining 'MVP types' as people who maintain their own web presence and participate extensively in forums as a part of their consulting practice.  I've seen a few postings with overtones of self-promotion from such people.  What I was stating is that I think this sort of thing is not wholly inappropriate if the trumpet-blowing actually refers people to material that is relevant to the question.

Comment: As long as the material is relevant and not complete bollocks I see no reason not to say 'Look! Here's a bunch of articles I wrote on this subject.' rather than reinvent the wheel.